# @Retry fallbackMethod not registered

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

I'd like to use *resilience4j-spring-boot2* in our Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE project to retry the failed requests against a third party service. However, I'm unable to register the fallbackMethod for some reason:

**pom.xml (relevant dependencies):**

```
<!-- Resilience4J and dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**application.yaml:**

```
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    exponentialBackoffBehaviour:
      maxRetryAttempts: 6
      waitDuration: 1s
      enableExponentialBackoff: true
      exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 2
```

**My Java code:**

```
@Retry(name = "exponentialBackoffBehaviour", fallbackMethod = "retryfallback")
private List<Applicant> requestApplicantList(HttpHeaders headers) throws JsonProcessingException {
    // This always returns 500 because is mocked
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(headers), String.class); 
    return objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<Applicant>>() {});
}

private List<Applicant> retryfallback(HttpHeaders headers, Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("retryfallback");
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

"retryfallback" is never printed in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The anotations only work on public methods not private.

Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring's AOP framework, private methods are by definition not intercepted. For JDK proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be intercepted. With CGLIB, public and protected method calls on the proxy are intercepted (and even package-visible methods, if necessary). However, common interactions through proxies should always be designed through public signatures.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!

I found out that the method should not only be public but also be the entry point of the class. Is this behaviour intended?

Comment: As "entry point" I mean something as follows: if A calls B.f() and B.f() has the annotation Retry, the annotation Retry works perfectly. However, if B.f() calls another public method inside the same object, let's suppose it B.f2() and B.f2() has the annotation Retry, then this annotation Retry won't work. In this case, this would be the stack trace: A -> B.f() -> B.f2()